# Scala Process for Linux is stuck

Tags: scala, unix, process, cat

I'm trying to use Scala Process in order to concate two files and send the result to a new file.
The code works fine, but when i remove the permissions to the folder, it seems to be stuck.

Here is the code:

```
   val copyCommand = Seq("bash", "-c", "cat \"" + headerPath + "\" \"" + FilePath + "\"")
   Process(copyCommand).#>>(new File(FileWithHeader)).!
```

Comment: Why do you run this through `bash`, and not `cat` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preformed the concatination in the same comend without creating new file and it's work fine:

```
 val copyCommand = Seq("bash", "-c", "cat \"" + headerPath + "\" \"" + FilePath + "\">FileWithHeader")
 Process(copyCommand).#!
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help (without invoking `bash`)?

```
import sys.process._
(Seq("cat", "file-1.txt", "file-2.txt") #>> new java.io.File("files-1n2.txt")).!
```